# Can't accept PayPal payment with only credit card while through mobile I can

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have business  PayPal account. I created `HTML` button - **"pay now"** to accept payments on my site. After clicking on, the user redirected  to secure Paypal page, and can pay with Paypal account but not pay with only credit card number.

If I try to pay with my mobile, this option in enable and I can pay only by credit card! I saw some answers to this similar problem saying to turn on the "PayPal Account Optional" option. I searched in all my account, and didnt found this option.

Anyone know something about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it may only seem like that on mobile.
The phrasing is different, but both work off the same configuration, so would behave the same if you were to check out.

Guest checkout is not available in all countries PayPal is available in. Plus, your email address needs to be confirmed on your account (this is often overlooked) and the guest checkout option ('PayPal account optional', available under 'Payment receiving preferences') must be enabled.
If you cannot find this option under 'Payment receiving preferences', it's likely because the option is not available for your country.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @PayPal_Robert, actually this was enabled a few days ago and suddenly it stop working. Also my country works with this option for sure (it worked before). The email address is confirmed.